# vim shell command integration

Tags: vim

Ok, I have rather simple question: How can one bind `vim` command/hotkey to execute some complicated shell-script?

E.g. I want to optimize base64-inlined images inside css files. I know, that in shell it would be something like:

```
echo `selection` > /tmp/img.png.b64
base64 -d /tmp/img.png.b64 > /tmp/img.png
optipng -o7 /tmp/img.png
base64 -w 0 /tmp/img.png > `selection`
```

I want to put `selection` into the script and then get result of script execution and replace selected content with that result.
I see the workflow as selecting base64 part in visual block mode and type e.g. `:'<,'>optipng` or press some hotkey.
The question is how to setup vim to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim allows to *filter* line(s) through an external command with `:[range]!{cmd}`. If your `optipng` command can take input from stdin and print to stdout, you can use it directly; else, with the help of a small shell script wrapper. See `:help :range!` for details.

One limitation is that this only works for **whole lines**, not parts, even when visually selected. You can get around this with the [vis plugin](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1195); it would then be something like:

```
:'<,'>B !optipng -o7
```

Comment: I suppose, I'd prefer parsing `base64` part inside css rule (to vis plugin). Thank you for solution.